# import * causes "global name 'emailtools' is not defined"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, python-import, nameerror

Got a slight problem with some appengine code that I can't work out (may just be because it's late)

I have a folder called modules that has the following items:

```
-modules
 : __init__.py (blank)
 : checklogin.py
 : customhandlers.py
 : datastoretools.py
 : emailtools.py
```

In my code I use all of these, therefore I'm doing this to import them:

```
from modules import *
```

Everything works bar emailtools. This:

```
emailtools.sendNotificationEmail('assignee',report,True)
```

Results in this error:

```
File "/home/tom/dev/ad-project/handlers/reporterhandler.py", line 42, in get
emailtools.sendNotificationEmail('assignee',report,True)
NameError: global name 'emailtools' is not defined
```

This happens wherever I try to use it, but the other three work perfectly fine, any ideas why? Or should I just import them all rather than using *?

Comment: Aside: "modules" != "Modules". This is not the cause of today's problem, but do try to spell the name the same in both places.

Comment: Are you **certain** that `__init__.py` is blank? I can't reproduce your behavior with a blank `__init__.py`. Please produce & copy-paste the shortest possible program that demonstrates the error. See http://SSCCE.ORG/ for more details.

Comment: Certain the __init__.py is blank. And 'Modules' was a typo, the dir is named "modules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't work at all. It seems that this wildcard is not the only one You have used. Maybe other modules came from other wildcards.

In any cases wildcard is undesirable
according to `PEP 8`:

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance).

P.S. I assume You use windows otherwise `Modules` can't be imported as `modules` I think.

Comment: I was looking for this exact statement when trying to decide how to import the modules, but couldn't find it so used import * anyway. Thanks for clearing that up, I'll import them by name. 

Also, I'm on Linux, never assume. And "Modules" was a typo, "modules" is the name of the directory.

Comment: Also, that is the only wildcard that I've used and I only used it as this directory only contains these modules, all of which I am using.